# How to pass googlemap places array result from angular 5 ts to html

Tags: typescript, google-maps-api-3, angular5

im a beginner in angular 5.
im trying to passing nearby restaurants result using googlemap from angular 5 ts to html but not sure where to create the array in typescript and how to pass the array into html when search for "restaurant".

i have try create javascript function to capture value and pass to component html but still fail.

anyone can help me ?

```
ngOnInit() {
      var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(3.147609, 101.698625),
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement,mapProp);
      var map = this.map;
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      var input = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('pac-input');

      var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);


      map.addListener('click',function(event) {



   infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);

   infoWindow.open(map);


    });



      map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {

        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
      });

      var markers = [];

      searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {


        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
          return;

        }


        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {

          marker.setMap(null);


        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();      


        places.forEach(function(place) {


          if (!place.geometry) {
            console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
          }


          var icon = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
          };




          // Create a marker for each place.
          markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
          }));
            console.log(place.name);
          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            // Only geocodes have viewport.

            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);

          }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      });
  }

}
```

Ben

Comment: If you have a restaurants details array, Then assign the array to the variable. Then you can use the variable directly and display the value in your html file. You can achieve it by using  *ngFor.

Answer (score 0):

I sadly can't comment yet : Why do you need to pass an array to your HTML ? I would suggest to manipulate the DOM using typescript to add elements in your HTML to display.

The workflow that comes to my mind when I read your question is the following :

- Get the user position by using navigator.geolocation (see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation) to get more details)
- Get the places nearby by using the nearby search requests (see [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=fr#PlaceSearchRequests) for this step)
- Fill a list with the desired informations (Place name, exact location, marker on your map, link to user reviews...) and create HTML elements (if it could be useful for you, you can add JQuery to your project to make it easier)

Comment: the array consist of restaurant info nearby provided by "var places = searchBox.getPlaces();". initial planning is to pass back to html component then use *ng-repeat ="let place of places"  to loop the info out.

Comment: currently whats build is user able to search using initautocomplete to reflect the map. so when search restaurant i will generate a list of store info with address and photo. could you suggest how to "manipulate the DOM using typescript to add elements in your HTML to display." from your reply?

Comment: Ok so the only thing you have to do is to create a model for your place, with the different informations needed to work with. When google give you the places, you have a lot of informations to process and it'll be easier for you if you build an object with only the desired fields. You don't have to manipulate the DOM in this case since your *ng-repeat do the work for you, all you need to do is to use in the "html component" the place var. Don't forget to declare the "places" var in your component script file (the .ts) for it to be used in the html component.